# Confused about traversing a class hierarchy with polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

Say I have a superclass called Fish, and a subclass called Tuna.  I don't understand why this works:

```
Fish f;
Tuna t = new Tuna();

f=t;  // I am confused about this statement
f.swim();  // (Tuna's swim method is invoked)
```

Why is the fish variable allowed to "become involved with" (for want of a better phrase) the more specialized Tuna object?  The way that my obviously erroneous "noob OOP Java brain" works is:

Tuna "is a" Fish is OK.  Fish "is a" Tuna isn't OK.  Therefore f=t shouldn't be OK, and t=f should be OK.  But from my example above, the opposite is true!

Thanks very much for any help on this.  I apologize in advance for my ignorance, as I have only just begun to learn Java.

**Edit**.  Thanks a lot for all replies below.  From them, I now understand that:

The variable called f is of type Fish, and as such, is allowed to contain the data value (object reference) located inside the variable called t, as t refers to a Tuna object, and is therefore of a compatible type for f to use.  It's compatible because a tuna is a fish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `f` variable is a reference. That can be a null reference, or a reference to any object which "is a fish". As a `Tuna` object is a `Fish` object, it's fine to copy the value from `t`, which must either be a null reference or a reference to a `Tuna` object.

Assignment *just* copied the value of the expression on the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side. That's all it does.

To put it another way: anything you can do to a `Fish`, you can do to a `Tuna`. So there's no value of `t` such that:

```
f = t;
f.swim();
```

is nonsensical. (`t` could be a null reference of course, but that's not seen as a problem in the type system as such.) There will *always* be an appropriate `swim` method to call, so long as `t` is non-null.

Compare that with a different type. If we had:

```
String s = "foo";
f = s;
f.swim();
```

then *that* wouldn't make sense, because you can't ask a `String` to swim.

The type safety rules ensure that you can never try to call a method (or access a field) and find that you're using a type for which that method/field simply doesn't exist. The fact that `Tuna` extends `Fish` means that anything you can do with a "general" fish, you can do with a tuna too.

Comment: Strings can't swim? OMG! I was enlightened!

Answer (score 2):

You are close, but you are wrong in just one statement.

> Tuna "is a" Fish is OK

I agree - this implies statement f=t (fish=tuna) to be correct.

> Fish "is a" Tuna isn't OK

I agree - this implies that statement t=f(tuna=fish) to be incorrect.

> . Therefore f=t shouldn't be OK, and t=f should be OK

I disagree, due to your statemets above you just said something opposite.
In last qoute you said that every fish is a tuna (t=f) and not every tuna is fish (f=t) - that is obviously wrong.

If tuna is a fish, than F=T becouse any tuna will be a fish. But we cannot say that every fish is a tuna can we?

You have to remember that `=` does not means equality (whitch `==` does in java), and for better understanding, try reading those statemets from right to left.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I agree, reading the "assignment copy action" from right to left helps to clarify the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You have Fish Super Class which has swim method, and Tuna is subclass of Fish.
So 
Tuna is a Fish  : Its Ok
But Fish is a Tuna  : is not ok.
Same
You can assign tuna ref to the fish ref but fish ref can not to the tuna.
So

```
public class Fish {
    public void swim(){
         System.out.print("Hello Fish");
    }
}

public class Tuna extends Fish{
    public void swim(){
        System.out.print("Hello Tuna");
    }


    public static void main(String[] ar){
       //Case A 
       Fish f=new Fish();
       Tuna t;
       t=(Tuna) f;//wrong - it will not cast to tuna object
       t.swim();
      //Case B  //correct
       Fish f;
       Tuna t=new Tuna();
       t=f 
       t.swim();

   }
}
```